# Pragmatically Get Count of Pivot Table Data

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Suppose I have some sample data like so:

[image]

and I create a Pivot Table and order by Product > Sales Rep > Sales

[image]

If I want the # of sales `John` had for `Product1` I would do `=GETPIVOTDATA("Sales",$A$3,"Product","Product1","Sales Rep","John")`

But how would I get a count of the entries there are. i.e. for `Product1`, `John` had `4` and `Kevin` had `2`

Is it possible to get this count using `GETPIVOTDATA()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this you need to add another Sales field to the values section and change the "Summarize By" to Count. Then the formula will =GETPIVOTDATA("Count of Sales",$A$3,"Product","Product1") will get you the count of Product Overall.